# How can I stamp turtle instead of pen?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this part of my code that runs a function, but I need to know how to stamp my first and last initial with the turtle shape in python instead of drawing by pen, I don't know how to do it. This is just the part of the code that needs editing within the function. If anyone knows how to do this please help ! :(

```
def draw_last_initial(turtle):
    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(125,-250)
    turtle.down()

    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.circle(50,180)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(200)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.circle(50,180)
    

def draw_first_initial(turtle):
    turtle.pensize(5)
    turtle.pencolor("navyblue")

    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(-220,50)
    turtle.down()

    turtle.left(70)
    turtle.forward(200)
    turtle.right(140)
    turtle.forward(200)
    turtle.left(180)
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.left(70)
    turtle.forward(69)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get turtle shape instead of pen try this  in your code.

```
turtle.shape('turtle')
```

Comment: Thank you! How do I get it to stamp the entire letter now?